# Install software on Android tablets automatically

Tags: samsung, samsung-knox

Our company purchased 100's of Samsung Tablets.
We need to install Samsung KNOX on all of them.
Right now, we need to power on every device and manually connect to WiFi and download Knox.
I'm wondering if there's any alternative where we can just connect it to a computer and have some software on  the computer that will connect to the tablet and take care of the all the setup steps.

Comment: How about mobile device management (MDM) Software?

Comment: You have to purchase special zero touch enrollment devices, then you can manage them: [Android zero touch device enrollment](https://www.android.com/enterprise/enrollment/). Regular devices have to be set-up manually.

Comment: @alecxs MDM first needs to be installed on the device. I don't know if there's any hardware/software out there that will allow us to plug the device into a terminal and have the MDM automatically installed